# What will the policy of aws sqs which is tigger by multiply s3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have S3 bucket and on object-put event I trigger SQS queue and received queue in my instance and process it,

Access policy of sqs is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:abcd",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:abcd",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's working fine for me but now I want to use the same queue in a two different bucket, I tried policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:abcd",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ca-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:abcd",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>",
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name2>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I didn't work, So anybody please help me to find what will be the Access policy of using same sqs queqe in two different bucket

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" what is the specific error?

Comment: On saving policy I get
"InvalidAttributeValue: Invalid value for the parameter Policy."

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: Okay @pciunkiewicz I will be more specific next time Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current policy is not valid JSON. To specify multiple `ArnLike` values you need to use a list:

```
    "ArnLike": {
      "aws:SourceArn": ["arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>",
             "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name2>"]
    }
```